# Sublime Code Highlighting in PHP doesn't work if no PHP Tags found

Tags: php, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime and some PHP files have no enclosing PHP Tags. This confuses Sublime, and no code-highlighting happens. Even Setting the syntax to PHP will still show un-highlited code

**Problem:** Without Tags

[image]

**Expected:** With Tags

[image]

Anyone Idea?

Comment: You just can't!! If it doesn't have php own opening tag, then it is not php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML
>   mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the
>   end. For this reason, any code inside the target file which should be
>   executed as PHP code must be enclosed within [valid PHP start and end tags](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

Sublime Text is merely following this recommendation!

Comment: Yes, but you can open a C++ File and tell sublime to highlight it as Python. Following convention is ok, but in different use cases, you want to break conventions.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't think you can weigh-off an individual problem against the overall practicality of following the standard. Most people will likely appreciate the hint that their code is missing an opening tag. If you need this so badly, why don't you edit the default syntax file to match your preference? It looks trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime needs an opening tag to see it as a php file.

You can put

```
#<?php
```

At the top of the file if you don't want to.

PHP sees it as a comment, Sublime won't. And thus fixing syntax highlighting.

Comment: This is a solution... but i don't want to add noise to my files. In a project folder i have a lot of files. I kinda get the logic, if you have embedded php in html, it may highlight them independently, which is a cool feature, but makes included code useless.

Comment: Then add an opening PHP tag. It's the one or the other. Those are the two solutions that work.

Answer (score 0):

Because php is an language design to embed in html code, the php mark `<? php` help code interpreter to distinguish php code from html. 
E.G

```
<title>
     <?php
            echo 'This is php code'
    ?>
</title>
```

I thought you just can not highlight the pho code without the php mark in sublime and you should not write php code without php mark.